# Can I call Marshall.ReleaseComObject in a Finalizer?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, finalizer

I have found on our code base code like this:

```
if (disposing)
{
    ....
}
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(comObject)
```

As the comObject is in fact a .Net object (a RCW, right?) is it safe to call it from the Finalizer?

Is it possible that it has been already released?

Comment: No, that is not safe, an RCW already has its own finalizer.  Which first of all makes the code completely unnecessary.  More severely, since finalization order is not deterministic you might be calling ReleaseComObject() on an object that is already destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, if you put it as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: Surely you can post a better answer?   I don't know what happens when you call ReleaseComObject() on a destroyed object, I never got this wrong intentionally.

Comment: @HansPassant: sorry, I don't get you. I was asking just to move the comment to an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer as I can't do it on a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Hans Passant` said:

> No, that is not safe, an RCW already has its own finalizer. Which
>   first of all makes the code completely unnecessary. More severely,
>   since finalization order is not deterministic you might be calling
>   ReleaseComObject() on an object that is already destroyed

So the call must be inside the if (disposing).